# Sitecore SolrNet - The given key was not present in the dictionary error

Tags: sxa, solr, sitecore-api

We are using SolrNet open source client in Sitecore 9.0 update2 and SXA 1.7 version. 
We have written this code to get SolrConnection:

```
Assert.ArgumentNotNull(searchcontext, "searchcontext");
var connection = new SolrConnection("http://localhost:8984/solr" + "/" + searchcontext.Index.Name);            
try
{           
    Startup.Init<PageContentSearchResultItem>(connection);//if not specified, runtime error -> ISolrConnection not declared                 
}
catch (System.Exception)
{//suppress error
}
ISolrOperations<PageContentSearchResultItem> solr = Startup.Container.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<PageContentSearchResultItem>>();
return solr;
```

Solrnet search is working as expected without error, But when we try to access other SXA pages, it is throwing below error:

```
The given key was not present in the dictionary. 
[ActivationException: Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type ISolrMoreLikeThisHandlerQueryResultsParser`1, key ""]
```

[image]

Any Ideas how to fix this issue.

Comment: Why are you accessing the indexes directly and not using the Sitecore Search API?

Comment: SolrNet api has built in features(Boosting, highlight, spell check, predictive search) we can execute query to get all of the above features, Where as Sitecore search API has less features, we may end up writing more code

Comment: It looks like `ISolrMoreLikeThisHandlerQueryResultsParser` is not registered correctly with the container. How are you registering all of the SolrNet interfaces? It looks to me like they are not registered correctly with the ServiceCollection. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784507/simple-injector-and-solrnet

Comment: Also - have you changed the version of SolrNet that Sitecore ships with? Looking closer at the stack trace, this is one of the SXA components trying to use the Sitecore Search API and its failing because it can't load that type in. So it could be a version incompatibility issue.

Comment: I am using same version as Sitecore ships with and still getting same error. SXA is out of the box components where we cannot see code, I am not sure how to register SolrNet interfaces in SXA. The shared link is using IUnityContainer. I am using SolrNet.Utils.Container where I don't get register method option

Comment: @User464 We have updated SearchDataource class (and rest of custom data sources) with additional checks so that those classes logic won't be triggered when you don't use directly. So, if you will update to upcoming SXA 1.8.1 you should not see that exception as I think it's related to not necessary SearchDatasource call. BUT! There is still something wrong with your configuration, probably you have some issues with DI conainer and registration of services. I strongly suggest not using custom DI containers. Remove IUnityContainer and use Microsoft container which is used in Sitecore and SXA.

Comment: @User464 - Hi , were you able to resolve this issue ?